# Are we paying less attention to the meta.academia's tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

When I look at the [tags](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) and their wikis and excerpts on [meta site](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/) of [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) on Stack Exchange and I compare them to other meta websites at Stack Exchange such as [meta.mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags), [meta.tex](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) and etc., I can easily understand that we do not have so rich wikis for the tags on our meta website.

Should we review the tags, their wikis, excerpts and descriptions on the meta site of Academia? If yes, what policy should this review have?

Comment: This site is referred to as just "Academia", "Academia.SE", or "Academia Stack Exchange" - the phrases "the Academia" "the Academia website" or "the Academia's website" are not grammatically correct.

Comment: @ff524 Thank you but, In which part of this question did I use those wrong phrases? Also, why are those phrases *grammatically* wrong? Because I have seen that the TeX website on Stack Exchange is referred to by TeX.SX.

Comment: @ff524 I opened a question on meta about the correct way to refer to the Academia to have it available to all the users. Please kindly take a look at it or post an answer there.

Comment: That comment was in reference to the tag excerpt edits you suggested connected to this post, not the content of this question. (Minor grammar details like that don't really matter in posts, but tag wiki excerpts should really have correct grammar.)

Answer (score 2):

The Academia.SE meta is a lot less active than many of those other ones, so I suppose it's not surprising it it's got less structured and organized tags as well.

I'd say: if you're psyched for it, go for it!  As always, of course, it's a good idea to post your plans to chat and/or meta to get a sense of how well they agree with the rest of the community before making big changes.

Answer (score 1):

I basically have OSD about tracking, organizing, classifying, and taxonomy-ing stuff, and it has even leaked into my research. But what I have learned the hard way is that there is no point in providing a lot of organization if you are not actually using the resulting classifications. Basically, write-only metadata just produces overhead.

Hence, I would not ask what kind of tags we *do not* have, but rather what kind of tags are *missing* from a user perspective. Do we have indications that people are not finding the meta-questions they are looking for? If yes, I am all in favor of adding more and better tags. If no, why bother?

Comment: I don't think "why bother if nobody will use them" is a great argument. But "adding unnecessary taxonomy makes tags harder to keep track of and makes the site less intuitive to use" might be.

Comment: @ff524 I am not sure if I understand. Are you arguing that we should create tags even if they are not needed, or that there actually is support of the idea that specific tags are missing?

Comment: *"I don't think "why bother if nobody will use them" is a great argument."* - To be fair, "Let's create more tags because others have them as well" isn't a great argument, either :D

Comment: I agree with you that we shouldn't create tags that are not needed. Your main argument seems to be "it isn't worth the effort to create tags that aren't needed," which isn't a great argument if someone *likes* creating tags and wants to expend this effort just for fun. I think a more compelling argument against creating unnecessary tags is that tag proliferation makes the site more confusing and less intuitive to use.

Comment: @ff524 ok, I did not consider the case that somebody would want to create tags for fun, no matter if they are needed or not. If this is the case, they can of course go ahead.

Comment: I don't necessarily think they *should* go ahead. A very detailed, planned-out taxonomy can be difficult for newcomers to use (compared to a taxonomy that evolved more naturally out of the natural ways that people tag questions).

Comment: (Although actually, I think this question is about tag wiki excerpts for existing tags, not new tags)

Comment: @ff524 Actually, my question is about creating and editing wikis and excerpts for existing tags.

Comment: @ff524 I agree with this part of your comments: *I think a more compelling argument against creating unnecessary tags is that tag proliferation makes the site more confusing and less intuitive to use.*